# Manger (par / de) lui-même

Tags: prépositions

> Elle mange elle-même.
>
> Elle mange **par** elle-même.
>
> Elle mange **d**'elle-même.

Un bébé qui est capable de manger sans aide ou un lapin devant lequel il ne faut pas tenir sa verdure et qui mange tout seul ses feuilles.

Est-ce que les trois phrases sont correctes dans ce contexte ? Laquelle est préférable, la première ?

Answer (score 2):

1. *Elle mange **elle-même*** : Possible mais peu courant sans complément (et dans ce cas avec un sens souvent différent), voire controversé.
2. *Elle mange **par elle-même*** : Le sens me semble bon, le style un peu soutenu.
3. *Elle mange **d'elle-même*** : Signifie plutôt qu'il ne faut pas lui dire de manger, que c'est elle qui prend l'initiative de manger.

Pour un animal, la phrase qui me vient à l'esprit est ***elle se nourrit toute seule***, et pour un bébé, ***elle mange toute seule***.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135949/discussion-on-answer-by-jlliagre-manger-par-de-lui-meme).

Answer (score 1):

Ce bébé, avant il fallait lui tenir la  cuillère devant la bouche, maintenant il mange  **par lui-même**. (Autonomie d'action)

Ce bébé, avant il fallait le supplier de manger, maintenant il mange **de lui-même** (Autonomie de décision)

Est-ce que ton bébé a toujours besoin d'une nounou pour ses repas ?
Non, il mange **lui-même** (Autonomie de la personne)